# How to connect private network through android device

Tags: android

I just want to access private network(like office domain) from my android device.What are all the necessary things to do this.An how could i do this?I need some ideas regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

Android device connect via Wi-Fi

So there are few things to be set

Go to settings->wi-di

In menu  select advance option and set following details

1) IP address
2) Gateway
3) Netmask
4) DNS1

set these values on your android phone for private network

Comment: i can able to set it on device.But how could i connect with private network(office system). Is it a hard task to do?

Comment: did you set above things in android phone

Comment: i just want to configure on system end.so only i can able to set above options